# Update Data after update the original Data in another sheet Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm get data from another sheet. first sheet is called "sheet1" and second called "sheet2".
this is my code:

```
function getdata(sheetName) {

   if (sheetName == ""){
     return "";
   } else {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
     var val = ss.getRange("A1").getValue(); // "A1" is the value what I need to get from "sheet1"
     return val;
```

"A3" is the name sheet name value is "sheet1".

I add `=getdata(A3)` in "sheet2" to get value from "sheet1" all work fine.

but the problem after change data in "sheet1" in cell "A1" the data not changing in "sheet2" why?

I want I if changing data in origin "sheet1" need changing automatic in "sheet2".

any Editing for that problem

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add a checkbox to your sheet in an available cell and include that cell in the second parameter of your function. Assuming the checkbox is in A1, your function becomes

```
=getdata(A3,A1)
```

even if that parameter is absent of your custom function. Then put an edit function as following

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sh.getName()!='main'){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('main');
    ss.getRange("A1").setValue(!ss.getRange("A1").getValue());
  }
}
```

assuming "main" is the name of the sheet where your formula is located. The change of value in main!A1 will re-activate the formula. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FJFGDJQsl9NrJa7IQwQRjwyYvG4QqQhGoytQkET1MT8/copy

Comment: Thanks Brother this range `ss.getRange("A1").setValue(!ss.getRange("A1").getValue());` is for checkbox

Comment: yes, so that each time the box is checked/unchecked